# Why does converting VARGRAPHIC to NUMERIC from column does not work?

Tags: sql, db2

Here is my data

```
create table testtable(realise vargraphic(36 CODEUNITS16))


delete from testtable@
insert into testtable values ('+000000000418734.00000')
```

When I do this, the result is `418734.00000` :

```
select cast(cast('+000000000418734.00000' as vargraphic(36 CODEUNITS16)) as numeric(18,5))  
from testtable
```

But when I do this, I've got an error `SQL0413N  Overflow occurred during numeric data type conversion.`

```
select cast(realise as numeric(18,5))
from testtable
```

Why does the conversion do not work from my column `realise` ?

I'm working with :

```
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.4.4", "s1902261400", "DYN1902261400AIX",
and Fix Pack "4a".
Product is installed at "/opt/IBM/DB2/V11.1_4".
```

Comment: Probably: The first is the conversion of a specific and known value, the other the generic conversion based on table metadata without touching the values.

Comment: Cannot recreate your symptom using v11.1.4.6 or v11.5.x  . Consider applying the latest fixpack.

Comment: Tried with another version, same result : 
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.4.5", "s1911120100", "DYN1911120100AIX",
and Fix Pack "5".
Product is installed at "/opt/IBM/DB2/V11.5".

Comment: The value +000000000418734.00000 has 15 digits before decimal point and 5 after, a numeric(20,5) would be needed if one of the two first digits was not zero. Is there such a case in your table ?

Comment: No, I created testtable to be sure of that, there is only one line

Comment: It works at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=95fb0112bd097dbe77272dd2ec2c9aee) link with 11.1.4.4. You may edit the example to reproduce the problem. Post your own link with it.